# Is it possible to configure the directory where Cargo caches the crates it downloads?

Tags: caching, rust, rust-cargo

In GitLab's CI, I can breakdown my build into stages and each stage can pass artifacts to the next configuration:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - target/
    - Cargo.lock
```

However, if the cache directory is outside the project directory or the `/cache` directory, it becomes hard to pass those artifacts along. I need to tell Cargo a good place to put (and look for) its cached crates.

In my case, I wish to use `/cache/cargo/registry/...` rather than `~/.cargo/registry/...`. or `/usr/local/cargo/registry/...`.

Bonus points for doing that via an environment variable.

Answer (score 11):

[Found it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads):

```
variables:
  CARGO_HOME: "/cache/cargo/"
```